# Map single character to another plane in unicode-math

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

In my document, I need to use a certain main font that lacks most mathematical symbols. For best results, I chose to stick to the main font for what is available, e.g. latin letters and numbers. Also, as is the case for most fonts, the PI glyph is available. Thus, I chose the following setup (not the real fonts):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range=\muppi,Color=red]
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range=\mitpi,Color=blue]


\begin{document}

$\pi$, $\mitpi$ and $\muppi$

\end{document}
```

However, the italic PI symbol does not show up. To my understanding, this is due to the fact that `\mitpi` tries to extract the glyph from the italic plane which is missing. I would rather want it to extract it from the upright plane and use the italic font variant instead.

In the docs, I read that for more general cases, one might use `range=it->up`, but that affects all italic symbols. How can this be restricted to just one single symbol? (I tried `\mitpi->\muppi`, but it gives me a "missing number" error.

Comment: Honestly I'd just put `\renewcommand{\mitpi}{\ensuremath{\mathit{\muppi}}}` after `\begin{document}`, but someone else might know the "right way" to do this.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to use a different font for math symbols. For example `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}`. Stix Two is a Times based font, so it will be a better combination for Times fonts than latinmodern. In addition, Stix Two has defined a very very large set of symbols, including those you mention.

Comment: @LuisTurcio I just used Times as an example, because it is widely available. The real font is sans serif, so there are basically only two options (GeoNeohellenic or Fira). So this does not solve the problem. The idea is to use the math font for everything except for (latin) letters and numbers and the symbol PI, because these are present in the main font, whereas the other maths stuff is not.

Comment: `math-style=` option, following type-setting traditions/standards in mathematics,  overrides the font, making things more intertwined.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a unicode maths font - they have the relevant lookup tables defined.

[image: pi]

Mapping with `->` is for named ranges, I understand.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagella-Math}[range=\muppi,Color=red]
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagella-Math}[range=\mitpi,Color=blue]


\begin{document}

$\pi$, $\mitpi$ and $\muppi$

\end{document}
```

---

However, using a non-maths sans font *face* in a sense is a "trick" and gives the following:

The order of assignments is important - last one has effect.

Italic

[image: italic last]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}%[math-style=upright]
\setmathfont{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}[range={"03C0},Color=red]
\setmathfont{texgyreadventor-italic.otf}[range={"03C0,"1D708},Color=blue]






\begin{document}

$\pi$, $\mitpi$ and $\muppi$


$\symsfit{π}+\symsfup{π}$

\end{document}
```

and upright:

[image: upright last]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}%[math-style=upright]
\setmathfont{texgyreadventor-italic.otf}[range={"03C0,"1D708},Color=blue]
\setmathfont{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}[range={"03C0},Color=red]






\begin{document}

$\pi$, $\mitpi$ and $\muppi$


$\symsfit{π}+\symsfup{π}$

\end{document}
```

but not both for the same character; there will also be some interaction with `-math-style=` option normalising symbols to italic or upright whatever is inputted.

---

**Addendum**

It might be worthwhile to do a proper MWE, because Greek italic will have to come from the lowercase italic Greek math alphabet in the MAS block of a math font, or the (text) Greek and Coptic block of the italic font face file of a non-math font - because a math font (one file) has all the math alphabets (>24) but only one text face (usually regular), and a non-math font will have many files (each one a different face, including italic) but none of the files will have a MAS Unicode block (by definition).

[image: mapping pi]

Note that `math-style` still comes into play, because different standards choose differently whether lowercase Greek and uppercase Greek should be the same or not (upright versus italic).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS-Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Fira-Math}[Colour=red]%[math-style=upright]


\begin{document}

\par\bigskip
text mode (XITS-Math)


\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & ^^^^03c0 αβγ xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ\\
MAS & bold upright & \\
MAS & italic & \\
MAS & bold italic & \\
MAS & sans bold upright & \\
MAS & sans bold italic & \\
LLS & bb & ℼ\\
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip
math mode (Fira-Math)

%$ℼ$

\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & $^^^^03c0 αβγ  xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ$ \\
MAS & bold upright & $$\\
MAS & italic & $$\\
MAS & bold italic & $$\\
MAS & sans bold upright & $$\\
MAS & sans bold italic & $$\\
LLS & bb & $ℼ$\\
\end{tabular}


\setmathfont{XITS-Math}[range={"03C0},Colour=brown]


\par\bigskip
math mode (Fira-Math, with mapping for ^^^^03c0)

\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & $^^^^03c0 αβγ  xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ$ \\
MAS & bold upright & $$\\
MAS & italic & $$\\
MAS & bold italic & $$\\
MAS & sans bold upright & $$\\
MAS & sans bold italic & $$\\
LLS & bb & $ℼ$\\
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum 2**

Or both ways at once: mapping from a math font will feed MAS direct input and also the `\symit{}` command; while a non-math font can be used in a `\renewcommand\mitpi{...}`.

[image: two sources]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS-Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Fira-Math}[Colour=red]%[math-style=upright]


\begin{document}

\par\bigskip
text mode (XITS-Math)


\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & ^^^^03c0 αβγ xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ\\
MAS & bold upright & \\
MAS & italic & \\
MAS & bold italic & \\
MAS & sans bold upright & \\
MAS & sans bold italic & \\
LLS & bb & ℼ\\
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip
math mode (Fira-Math)

%$ℼ$

\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & $^^^^03c0 αβγ  xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ$ \\
MAS & bold upright & $$\\
MAS & italic & $$\\
MAS & bold italic & $$\\
MAS & sans bold upright & $$\\
MAS & sans bold italic & $$\\
LLS & bb & $ℼ$\\
\end{tabular}


\setmathfont{XITS-Math}[range={"03C0,"1D70B},Colour=brown]


\par\bigskip
math mode (Fira-Math, with mapping for ^^^^03c0 and ^^^^^^01d70b from XITS-Math)

\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & $^^^^03c0 αβγ  xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ$ \\
MAS & bold upright & $$\\
MAS & italic & $$\\
MAS & bold italic & $$\\
MAS & sans bold upright & $$\\
MAS & sans bold italic & $$\\
LLS & bb & $ℼ$\\
\end{tabular}




%\setmathfont{Noto Serif-italic}[range={"03C0},Colour=violet,Scale=2]
\newfontface\itgreek{Noto Serif-italic}[Colour=violet,Scale=2]
\RenewDocumentCommand{\mitpi}{}{${\itgreek ^^^^03c0}$}

\par\bigskip
math mode (Fira-Math, with renewcommand for italic ^^^^03c0 from non-m font)

\begin{tabular}{llc}
Greek & upright & $^^^^03c0  αβγ  xyz+ΓΔΘXYZ$ \\
Greek & italic symit & $\symit{^^^^03c0}$ \\
Greek & italic renewcommand mitpi & $\mitpi$ \\
MAS & bold upright & $$\\
MAS & italic & $$\\
MAS & bold italic & $$\\
MAS & sans bold upright & $$\\
MAS & sans bold italic & $$\\
LLS & bb & $ℼ$\\
\end{tabular}




\end{document}
```